# How to make a combobox column show only unselected items?

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox, devexpress

It's supposed to be a very common workflow, so I am surprised that neither C# gridview or DevExpress provides an easy way to do it.

Example:
MyColumn is a field of combobox type column. When a user tries to edit value in this field, he will have to choose a value in the dropdown list. When the grid has 1 row, he can choose from "value A", "value B" or "value C". If the user has chosen "value A" in the 1st row, then in the 2nd row the available values for MyColumn become "value B" and "value C".

Currently I am doing it in a dirty way with DevExpress , where I calculate the combobox repository (modify RepositoryItemComboBox.Items property) everytime after a delete, insert or modify operation, and in the CustomRowCellEdit event handler I assign the updated repository to the column. The code is very convoluted and brittle.

------update------
I just came up with a better example of a use case:
Say that the grid asks the user to select his 5 most favorite US states. So the column State is a combobox type column that initially has a list of 50 states. If the user selects CA for the 1st row, then in the 2nd row he will have only 49 states available to select. In this case, you always want values to be unique in each row or it would not make sense.

Comment: In simple terms, you want the combobox value to be unique for every row right?

Comment: Make a class which items you populate to the combobox. So your combobox get a List<MyClass>. In your class you define a key and value member for example and a Property "Status". This could be a bool flag. The comboboxes always show all items with status = true. So every combobox get the List<MyClass> at datasource and if you make a change you just change the status. Maybe this works in your case.

Comment: To Gian Acuna: Yes I do. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: To Sebi: right now the repository is not bound to a datasource, but its item list is added or removed programatically at run time. I'll see if your approach can work.

Comment: Sebi, I don't think DevExpress supports this: "The comboboxes always show all items with status = true." Or maybe I didn't find it. Can you give more specific instruction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution.

Handle the CustomRowCellEditForEditing event. In the handler, traverse all rows and get all selected items, and remove the selected items from the repositoryItemComboBox1.Items (suppose that's your column editor).
Of course, the logic is a little more complicated because you will also have to change the Items collection when user edits or deletes a row.

**Caution:**
**CustomRowCellEdit is the wrong way to go.** Because everytime RepositoryItemComboBox.Items is changed the event will fire.

Answer (score 1):

You might have thought of it; but just in case if you haven't:

I believe, rather than trying to change the repository every time, better to actually validate the selected value in the combo (in the onchange event of the combobox) and override the user selection for this item in case it is a duplicate.

Note: Also, changing the repository, I think, will have it's own share of issues; as changing the DataSource after every delete, insert or modify will alter the data in other combo boxes (Obviously, here I am assuming that all combos uses the same Datasource).

Comment: thanks. right now it's not bound to a datasource but there is indeed some issue. whenever the repository is modified, the CustomRowCellEdit will fires and cause some wacky behavior